# ROM programs on the Sony MSX HitBit HB-501

Tags: rom, msx

I have acquired a **Sony MSX HB-501** ***F*** (*F stands for France, it only defines the keyboard's layout*).

It is fully functionnal, I can play games from cartridges on it and it displays MSX-BASIC if no cartridges are inserted.

The problem is that I got it without its original manual, and so I have a hard time figuring out how some features work.

As it was a high-end personal computer at the time, I read that it has a few office programs in ROM, such as an address book and an agenda.

I know that if its in the computer's ROM, the settings must be saved to a data cartridge (there were 4KB data cartridges) or cassette tape.

My only problem being that I don't know how to run those programs from the ROM. Moreover, I'm not even sure there are any program in ROM as I couldn't find any relevant documentation on how to run them, I could only find mentions of their existence.

So, is there really any program stored in ROM on an Sony MSX HB-501 apart from MSX-BASIC? If so, how can I run them?

Comment: Hi you could take a look at the MegaFlashROM SSC+ SD
which you can load code from in to memory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 501 series only came with the bundled productivity software on tape, unlike earlier models like the HB-101P and HB-201P that had it in firmware.

> The provided English software on tape is the same as the built-in
>   firmware on HB-101P and HB-201P. [HB-501F](https://www.msx.org/wiki/Sony_HB-501F)

If you look at this description for the 101 series, for example, it states that

> The firmware is launched automatically when you boot the machine. It's
>   an English version of the original Japanese software ... from MSX-BASIC, you can go back to the Personal Databank with CALL HITBIT or _ HITBIT. [HB-101P](https://www.msx.org/wiki/Sony_HB-101P)

Its a menu you're presented with immediately that you have to exit out of to get to actually drop down to BASIC.